# Regex: Match double new lines but not within backticks

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all double new lines, but not within backticks. I am not familiar with lookbehinds, but I think that is what's needed here. This is what I've come up with this far: `` (?<!`)[\r\n]{2} ``. Somehow I need to add `.*?` or similar after the lookbehind and before the line break but I haven't figured it out yet.

Here you can see what should match, and what shouldn't.

```
        Some random text...
  // MATCH
        text after break
        haha text
  // MATCH
        `Hey,
  // NO
        here is some text!
  // NO
        and here is the end =)`
  // MATCH
        here is text
```

You can see my example here: https://regex101.com/r/wvrh77/1

How do I match all double new lines, but not those within backticks?

Comment: This can most probably be solved better with some code. What you ask for can be done with PCRE, ``/`[^`]*`(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\r\n?|\n){2}/``, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvrh77/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PCRE-compliant regex like

```php
/`[^`]*`(*SKIP)(*F)|\R{2}/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvrh77/3).

*Details*:

- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `` [^`]* `` - zero or more chars other than backtick
- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - skip the current match attempt, consider it a fail and start searching for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\R{2}` - two line break sequences.